# how to create api routes in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node.js and I want to create the routes for the CRUD operation like **"localhost:3000/create", "localhost:3000/retrieve", "localhost:3000/update"** and so on.

But in all the tutorials and blogs they have given the routes like ***"localhost:3000/#/api/cars", "localhost:3000/#/api/cars/create"*** so on.

Why this # symbol is by default assigned to the URL .
Can't we get rid of this **#** symbol and write the API route as /create /retrieve ?

If yes how we do so?

Anyone please help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `#` isn't actually sent to the server.  Can you link to one of these tutorials and quote the relevant text within your question?  They are likely Single Page Applications where the `#` is used as part of faux routing without doing actual page navigation.

Comment: @zero298

https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-design-with-node-js-26ccf66eab09

as in the above link they have made a single route to all the CRUD operations. Half of the tutorials are following these patterns.
But I don't need these type toutes. I want to write each route for each CRUD operation like for create- /create, retrieve- /retrieve, update- /update like so.

I hope you understood

Comment: @Meera you can follow https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9 . on creating express routes, you don't need a `#` route. you might only need it when building single page applications, where the routing of your application don't need to hit your server routes.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, let me share you a basic code to make your routes using node.js:

```
 /*
 *primary file for the api
 *
 * * */

 //dependencies 
const http = require('http')    
const url =require('url')
const StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder

const fs = require('fs')
//the server should respond to all requests with a string
 //a.1. Instantiating the HTTP server 
const httpServer = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
        unifiedServer(req,res)        
})
//start the HTTP server
httpServer.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log(`The server is listening on port 3000`)
})     

//All the server logic for  the http
const unifiedServer = (req,res)=>{
        //Get the url and parse it
        const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url,true)//true:indicates to parse the query string 
            //which means to set the parsedUrl.query value at the equivalent as if we had
            //sent this data to the query string module, so really we are using two modules
            //in one
        //Get the path
         const path = parsedUrl.pathname//the path of the user request
            //http://localhost:3000/foo...
         const trimedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g,'')

         //Get the query string as an object:
        const queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query //?mnp=abd

        //Get the http method:
        const method = req.method.toLowerCase() //get, post

        //Get the headers as an object
        const headers = req.headers //{foo:bar,fizz:buzz,...}

        //Get the payload, if any is the text: 'fdsfasdfsadfsd'
        const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8')//utf-8 is what kind of 
                //charset or encoding it can expect
                //payloads, as part of the http request, come in to the http server  as a string
                //so we need to collect that string as it comes in and then when the string tells
                //us what are the end cover last that into one covering thing before we can
                //figure out what the payload is
        let buffer = ''//string where we are going to append the incoming palyload as it comes
        req.on('data',data=>{
                buffer += decoder.write(data)
        })//when the request emit the event called 'data' (so, ON the event 
                //called data)

        req.on('end',()=>{//called regardless if it has a payload or not
                buffer += decoder.end()
                //choose the handler this request should go to. If one is not found use
                //not found handler
                const chosenHandler = typeof(router[trimedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? 
                router[trimedPath] : handlers.notFound
                //contruct the data Object to send to the handler:
                const data = {
                        'trimedPath':trimedPath,
                        'queryStringObject':queryStringObject,
                        'method':method,
                        'headers':headers,
                        'payload':buffer
                }
                //route the request to the handler specified in the router
                chosenHandler(data,(statusCode,payload)=>{
                        console.log(statusCode,payload)//es la data que esta en la 
                        //funcion sample del objeto handler
                        //use the status code  CALLED BACK by the handler or default
                        //to 200
                        statusCode = typeof(statusCode) == 'number' ? statusCode:200
                        //use the payload called back by the handler or default to and
                        //empty object
                        payload = typeof(payload)=='object' ? payload:{}

                        //convert the payload to a string
                        const palyloadString = JSON.stringify(payload)

                        //return the response
                        res.setHeader('content-Type','application/json')//telling ...
                        //that we are going to return an object:
                        //content-Type is the key ; application/json is the value
                        res.writeHead(statusCode)//usin the buil in function that comes on every
                        //response object received by the http server to write the status code

                        //now that the request has finished
                        //Send the response
                        res.end(palyloadString)
                        //Log the request path
                        console.log(`Returning this response` , statusCode , palyloadString)
                })
        })
        //console.log(`Request received with these headers: ` , headers )
        //console.log(`Request received on path: ${trimedPath} with method ${method}
        //and with this query string parameters `, queryStringObject)
}


//define the handlers
const handlers = {}
//ping handler
handlers.ping = (data,callback)=>{
        callback(200)
}
//ping handler
handlers.hello = (data,callback)=>{
        callback(600,{'greeting':'hello world'})
}
//Not found handler
handlers.notFound = (data,callback)=>{
        callback(404)//does not need a payload
}
//define a request router
const router = {
        'ping':handlers.ping,
        'hello':handlers.hello
}
```

Good Luck!